# change position of ActionBarDrawerToggle in toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

I get this situation. How to put the icon to a higher position? It seems to be cut off

[image]

Here is my java code

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nullToolbar), R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

my XML of the toolbar.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/nullToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnToolbarSearch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:padding="@dimen/image_button_padding"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />
                </RelativeLayout>

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nullToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            ...
```

Comment: or i think you can  use  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: I'll break my design if I do that. My AppBarLayOut contains more than one Toolbar

Comment: Oh.  Maybe you should have put the whole XML layout in your question.